# In Python, how can I patch a function from another file that's not imported locally?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm working on learning Pythonic test development, and stumbled across this seemingly counterintuitive issue. When I'm patching a function that is defined in the same file as the code under test, the `patch` works correctly. But when I `import` a function from a different file, the only way to get the `patch` working correctly is to make the `import` local instead of defining it at the top of the file.

Minimal reproduction:

a/b.py:

```python
from x.y import z


def c():
    print("In a.b.c")


class D:
    def do_stuff_with_a_b_c(self):
        print("In do_stuff_with_a_b_c")
        c()

    def do_stuff_with_x_y_z(self):
        from x.y import z
        print("In do_stuff_with_x_y_z")
        z()
```

x/y.py:

```python
def z():
    print("In x.y.z")
```

tests/d_tests.py:

```python
import inspect
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from x import y
from a.b import D


class DTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_do_stuff_with_a_b_c(self):
        print(f"In {inspect.stack()[0][3]}")
        D().do_stuff_with_a_b_c()

    @patch("a.b.c")
    def test_do_stuff_with_patched_a_b_c(self, a_b_c_method):
        print(f"In {inspect.stack()[0][3]}")
        D().do_stuff_with_a_b_c()

    def test_do_stuff_with_x_y_z(self):
        print(f"In {inspect.stack()[0][3]}")
        D().do_stuff_with_x_y_z()

    @patch("x.y.z")
    def test_do_stuff_with_patched_x_y_z(self, x_y_z_method):
        print(f"In {inspect.stack()[0][3]}")
        D().do_stuff_with_x_y_z()

    def test_do_stuff_with_patch_object_x_y_z(self):
        print(f"In {inspect.stack()[0][3]}")
        with patch.object(y, "z"):
            D().do_stuff_with_x_y_z()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I run the tests with the code as above, I get the following output:

```
In test_do_stuff_with_a_b_c
In do_stuff_with_a_b_c
In a.b.c
In test_do_stuff_with_patch_object_x_y_z
In do_stuff_with_x_y_z
In test_do_stuff_with_patched_a_b_c
In do_stuff_with_a_b_c
In test_do_stuff_with_patched_x_y_z
In do_stuff_with_x_y_z
In test_do_stuff_with_x_y_z
In do_stuff_with_x_y_z
In x.y.z
```

However, when I comment out the local import of `x.y.z` in `do_stuff_with_x_y_z`, I get the following output:

```
In test_do_stuff_with_a_b_c
In do_stuff_with_a_b_c
In a.b.c
In test_do_stuff_with_patch_object_x_y_z
In do_stuff_with_x_y_z
In x.y.z
In test_do_stuff_with_patched_a_b_c
In do_stuff_with_a_b_c
In test_do_stuff_with_patched_x_y_z
In do_stuff_with_x_y_z
In x.y.z
```

What is the the difference between the two forms that causes `patch` to work as expected in one scenario but not the other?

Comment: using foo bar Bar baz and buzz makes it very confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two cases - top-level versus local import - have to be handled differently while patching. You have to patch an object as used in the module, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6), or in [this blog post](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201908/why_your_mock_doesnt_work.html) by Ned Batchelder, who describes the problem in more detail.

In your first case, you import the module `z` at runtime *after* it has been patched, so the patched module is imported. In your second case (the more standard case of top-level import) you import the module *before* it is patched, and have now a reference to the unpatched `z` in your module `b`, so for the patching to work you have to patch *this reference*:

```py
@patch('a.b.z')
def test_do_stuff_with_patched_x_y_z(self, mocked_z):
   ...
```

To sum this up: you always have to check how the object to use is imported in the module to be tested. There are basically two cases:

- the object is imported like `import x` or `import x.y` (and used like `x.y.z`) - in this case it can be patched as `x.y.z`. The same is true if you import the module locally inside a function, as in your initial case.
- the object is imported like `from x.y import z` (or `from .y import z`) - in this case a local reference is created that refers to the object, and the patching shall be done for that reference (e.g. `a.b.z` in your case)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation of the differences between the import methods. I will try to update the example to be more readable.

Comment: I changed the naming. I'd appreciate your input on whether it makes a positive impact or not; if it does, would you mind updating your answer to match?

Comment: Certainly better readable - I updated the answer. There is only `buzz_method=None` left as an argument in your question - the name does not match (it is now the mocked `z`), and the default argument makes no sense here, as it is always set to the mock.

Comment: Updated. I changed the name to `x_y_z_method` and removed the default value. Thanks again!