# monkeypatch.setattr not working for requests call

Tags: python, python-requests, mocking, pytest, monkeypatching

I'm trying to make a test that calls an endpoint in my code which in return calls makes another request to another api. It's that second request that i want to mock for it to return a 500.

File structure:

```
/rootdir
  /src
    __init__.py
    ext_api_services.py
    member.py
    member_test.py
requirements.txt
```

Method to patch (ext.api_services.py)

```
def get_member(atr_1, atr_2, atr_3, atr_4):
    cmd = 'some/endpoint'
    return requests.get(cmd)
```

Test (member_test.py)

```
from . import ext_api_services

def substitue_func(atr_1, atr_2, atr_3, atr_4):
    print('getting fired?')
    a_dict = dict(response_code=500)
    return a_dict

def test_member_500(api_app, monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(ext_api_services, 'get_member', substitue_func)
    api_app.post('/some/other/endpoint')
```

Location where the substitue_func should be called (member.py)

```
from .ext_api_services import get_member
# some api code
resp = get_member(atr_one, atr_two, atr_three, atr_four)
```

I've tried doing

```
monkeypatch.setattr(ext_api_services, 'get_member.__code__', substitue_func.__code__)
monkeypatch.setattr('ext_api_services.get_member', substitue_func)
```

But that didn't work

Comment: You have to patch `get_member` in `member.py` - it has its own reference of `get_member` created by `import from...`.

Comment: Thanks!
This worked for me:

    monkeypatch.setattr(member, 'get_member', substitue_func)

Comment: In a [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62625882/12480730) to a related question I added some links that may help to understand this better - these are about `patch`, but the same is true for `monkeypatch`.