# How to mock a function called inside a class attribute?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, django-testing, python-unittest.mock

I have a class with an attribute that calls a function:

`users.mixins.py`:

```
from django.contrib import messages    
from ..utils.services import redirect_to_previous

class AdminRightsMixin:

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_admin:
            messages.warning(
                request, 'You must have administrator rights to view this page.'
            )
            redirect_to_previous(request)
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I want to test that `redirect_to_previous` is called, but I don't know how to mock this in my test.

For example:

```
@patch.object(AdminRightsMixin.dispatch, 'redirect_to_previous')
def test_admin_mixin(self, mock_class):
    // code
```

Results in `AttributeError: <function AdminRightsMixin.dispatch at 0x000001D54FDB6430> does not have the attribute 'redirect_to_previous'`

Comment: You have to mock `redirect_to_previous` from where it is imported - check [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6). If it is a function of `AdminRightsMixin`, you have to patch it in that class, e.g. `@patch.object(AdminRightsMixin, 'redirect_to_previous')`

Comment: Thanks, that still results in `AttributeError: <class 'AdminRightsMixin'> does not have the attribute 'redirect_to_previous'` presumably because it's not an attribute but a function inside an attribute?

Comment: Well, I don't know where it is defined - that was only a guess (wrong guess, as it is not called using 'self'', missed that) - but it is obviously a function that is either defined in this module, or imported from somewhere. Can you adapt your question to show where it comes from?

Comment: Yes of course, thank you. Please see the update.

Comment: I guess the path is `users/mixins.py`. In this case `@patch('users.mixins.redirect_to_previous')` should work, as the function reference you want to patch lives in that module. Check for example [my previous answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62625882/12480730).

Comment: Got it, if you want to add this as an answer I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: This has been answered before (like in my own answer linked in the previous comment), so it is probably not worth it. Glad I could help anyway!