# Cannot mock subprocess.check_call

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I want to write a test for this function while mocking `check_call` (I don't want it to be called):

```
from subprocess import check_call

def foo_method():
    check_call(["ls"])
    print("hello")
```

This is the test:

```
import unittest.mock
from scripts import foo_method

@unittest.mock.patch("subprocess.check_call")
def test_foo_method(subprocess_check_call):
    foo_method()
```

But the `check_call` function is always called and is not mocked. What is wrong with the test?

Comment: You have to patch the `check_call` imported in your module, e.g. `patch("mymodule.check_call")` - see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6), or for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62625882/12480730) a gave to a similar question.

Comment: It's a subtle point, but `foo_method` uses `scripts.check_call`, not `subprocess.check_call`. Both names refer to the same underlying object, but `patch` operates on *names*, not the things they refer to.

Answer (score 0):

You should patch the `check_call` method for `scripts.py` module. So the target to be patched should be `scripts.check_call`. For more info, see [where-to-patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch)

E.g.

`scripts.py`:

```py
from subprocess import check_call


def foo_method():
    check_call(["ls"])
    print("hello")
```

`test_scripts.py`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from scripts import foo_method


class TestScripts(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch("scripts.check_call")
    def test_foo_method(self, mock_check_call):
        foo_method()
        mock_check_call.assert_called_once_with(['ls'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

unit test result:

```
⚡  coverage run /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/python-codelab/src/stackoverflow/65601680/test_scripts.py && coverage report -m --include='./src/**'
hello
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
Name                                         Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/65601680/scripts.py            4      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/65601680/test_scripts.py      10      0   100%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                           14      0   100%
```