# Print statement executing but function call directly after failing assert_called

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

tl;dr: I know a code block I am testing with unittest is being executed because of a print statement, but a function directly after the print statement is failing an assert_called check. When running the code, the function is being called and exectued as expected.  Unclear why test is failing.

Code in function being tested:

```
from path.to import deliver_error

def handle_error(ARGS):
  if HANDLE_ERROR_BOOL:
    print('calling deliver_error')
    deliver_error(ARGS)
  else:
    # do something else
```

Test code:

```
class TestSampleRegistration(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp():
        # mock deliver_error
        mock_deliver_error_patch = patch("path.to.deliver_error", autospec=True)
        self.mock_deliver_error = mock_deliver_error_patch.start()
        self.addCleanup(mock_deliver_error_patch.stop)

    def test_handle_error(self):
        main.HANDLE_ERROR_BOOL = True
        handle_error(ARGS)
        self.mock_deliver_error.assert_called() # point of failure
```

Assertion failure:

```
AssertionError: Expected 'deliver_error' to have been called.
```

Captured stdout:

```
Captured stdout for test_main.MyTestClass.test_handle_error
  calling deliver_error
```

I KNOW:

- HANDLE_ERROR_BOOL is correctly set (print statement executed and showing up in stdout)
- deliver_error *should be getting called* since there is nothing between the print statement and the deliver_error call, and the print statement is being executed
- when running the actual code the function **is** being executed as expected

So why is the assert_called test failing?  Help very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You mock the wrong reference, see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6). Instead of mocking `path.to.deliver_error` you have to mock `mymodule.deliver_error`, provided that `handle_error` lives in `mymodule`. I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62624390/12480730).

Comment: Thank you @MrBeanBremen!  That solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Answering for the sake of others who might see this post:

As per MrBean Bremen's comment, the resolution was to update the mock from

```
class TestSampleRegistration(unittest.TestCase):
  def setUp():
    # mock deliver_error
    mock_deliver_error_patch = patch("path.to.deliver_error", autospec=True)
```

to

```
class TestSampleRegistration(unittest.TestCase):
  def setUp():
    # mock deliver_error
    mock_deliver_error_patch = patch("mymodule.deliver_error", autospec=True)
```